# Swing GUI in Java: Different elements won't layout properly for me

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, border-layout

I'm having trouble getting my GUI to do what I want it to. This is my first time using Swing, so I apologize in advance if this a dumb question. Much of my code is also copy/pasted from the samples at oracle.com, but I think I have a feel for what it's all doing.

In my Swing GUI, I currently have two elements: a JTable and a a JComboBox (which I believe is encompassed by a JScrollPanel). The way I want it formatted is with the ComboBox above the Table, but I can only seem to get it to go either to the left or right of it. I thought that I would be able to use this line:

```
add(charList, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
```

where "charList" is my ComboBox, but it doesn't seem to affect anything. No matter what I set it or the other element to, it still stays side to side.

Here is my complete code, all in one file:

```
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class MeleeEdit extends JPanel {
    private boolean DEBUG = false;

    public  String[] attributes = {
            "Initial Walk Velocity", "Walk Acceleration?", "Walk Maximum Velocity", "Slow Walk Max?"    
     };
    public  String[] description = {
            "N/A",
            "N/A, bruh",
            "N/A, BRUH",
            "N/A, BRUH!"    
     };

    public MeleeEdit() {
        super(new GridLayout(1,0));

        String[] characters = { "Captain Falcon", "Young Link", "Donkey Kong", "Doctor Mario", "Falco" };
        JComboBox charList = new JComboBox(characters);
        charList.setSelectedIndex(0);
        //petList.addActionListener(this);


        JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 600));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);


        table.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
        table.add(new JSeparator(SwingConstants.VERTICAL));
        table.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
        table.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));

        //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        //scrollPane.setLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //Add the scroll pane to this panel.
        add(charList, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }

    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        private String[] columnNames = {"Attribute",
                                        "Value",
                                        "Info",
                                        };
        private Object[][] data = initGrid();

        public Object[][] initGrid(){
            Object[][] tmp = new Object[3][3];
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i ++){
                tmp[i][0] = attributes[i];
                tmp[i][1] = new Float(4.5);
                tmp[i][2] = description[i];
            }
            return tmp;
        }


        public int getColumnCount() {

            return columnNames.length;
        }
        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }
        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];
        }
        public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
            return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
        }

        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            //Note that the data/cell address is constant,
            //no matter where the cell appears onscreen.
            if(col==1)
                return true;
            else
                return false;

        }

        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            if(value==null)
                return;
            data[row][col] = value;
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Melee Character Attribute Editor v0.1");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        MeleeEdit newContentPane = new MeleeEdit();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why it isn't working. Any suggestions?

Comment: `add(charList, BorderLayout.LINE_START);` ..OK `super(new GridLayout(1,0));` ..Huh?  Why give it border layout constraints when it is a grid layout?

Comment: Credit for trying to use the layout management API!

Answer (score 2):

- Change `super(new GridLayout(1,0));` to `super(new BorderLayout());`
- Change `add(charList, BorderLayout.LINE_START);` to `add(charList, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);` (personally, I prefer `BorderLayout.NORTH`, but I'm old school like that)

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more details

Comment: Wonderful, worked like a charm. Thanks a bundle! And again, my apologies for the solution being so simple but I'm just completely new to Swing.

Comment: @AndrewBischoff I'll give you credit for trying to use the layout manager API. It can confusing at first, but once you get use to it, you will never want to do without it ;)